# More symbionts or more hosts?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

Until 7th season of Deep Space Nine I was more than sure that there is always single symbiont and many hosts for it. If one host dies another one is brought for *the very same symbiont*.

Yet, in one of [first episodes of the 7th season](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/DS9_Season_7) (I don't recall the exact one), Ezri Dax mentions, in some chit-chat something about some experience or behavior shared by  "*the last five Daxes*".

I always thought that there was a single Dax symbiont hosted by Ezri, after it was hosted by Jadzia, after it was hosted by Curzon and so on.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you're not sure, ***investigate first what exactly is said***. Your entire question is based on an incorrectly remembered quote. [KIRA: "Isn't there a period of adjustment that joined Trills have to go through where people are comparing them to previous hosts? I'm sure it'll pass." -- EZRI: "You're right. The last five Dax hosts went through this."](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/557.htm)

Comment: 1 symbiant many host

Comment: @BCdotWEB My copy of this episode has weak audio and an obvious error in subtitles. Making mistakes doesn't actually allows you to yell at anyone. That bolding wasn't actually necessary. I do get your point without it... I have actually asked an even more stupid question and no one yelled at me in any comment on answer to it... Mr Know It All.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been noted in a comment, you've mis-heard the quote.

> **KIRA:** *Isn't there always a period of adjustment that joined Trills have to go through... when people are comparing them to
> previous hosts? I'm sure it'll pass.*
>
> **EZRI**: (sighs) *You're right. The last five Dax **hosts** went through this.*
>
> (beat)
>
> *That wasn't bad. You'd make a  pretty good counselor. Want to trade jobs?*
>
> <sub><sup>[Once More Unto the Breach - Original Screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/557.txt)</sup></sub>

There's only one Dax (the symbiont). Kurzon, Jadzia, Ezri and [all the others](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dax_(symbiont)#History) are merely its *hosts*, hence why they get the appellation Jadzia **Dax**, Ezri **Dax**, etc once joined.